# Vim filename/path completion

Tags: autocompletion

I know I can complete filenames/paths from the current directory using <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> ([`compl-filename`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#compl-filename)). That works great in combination with `set autochdir`, which changes the current directory to the directory of the active buffer.

However, I started using [airblade/vim-rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter) to make the current directory the "project" folder. Now filename completion always starts from the project folder.

The question: Is there a way to make the filename completion use the directory of the active buffer instead of the current directory? Or some other workaround?

Comment: C-xC-f always uses the current buffer's working directory, without any options to configure it (it doesn't support `path` either). It depends on what your intended use for vim-rooter is. Depending on what you want from it, we could use other plugins. Aside: I use youcompleteme, which completes paths from the directory of the current buffer if you start typing `./`. See https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/216jdd/youcompleteme_and_path_completion/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @muru mentioned, there are no options to configure the directory from which to complete path and file names.  It always uses the working directory of the window.

I've written a couple of functions and mappings to help with this. Behind the scenes, they change the local working directory (using `:lcd`) temporarily, then restore the previous working directory when done.

### Elephant

For reasons unknown to even me, I've called this micro-plugin *Elephant*.

Here's the code (copied from my [Vim config on GitHub](https://github.com/tommcdo/vimfiles/blob/acbfebde2fb468dbad05d8acf7d395727dfa0202/config/elephant.vim)):

```
let g:elephant_map = {
    \ 'f': function('elephant#current_file'),
    \ 'p': function('elephant#vcs_project')
\ }

function! elephant#prompt(base)
    let l:Fcn = get(g:elephant_map, a:base, function('elephant#identity'))
    let l:basedir = l:Fcn()
    execute 'lcd' l:basedir
    let l:file = fnamemodify(input(l:basedir.'/', '', 'file'), ':p')
    lcd -
    return fnamemodify(l:file, ':.')
endfunction

function! s:elephant_init()
    let l:base = getchar()
    return elephant#prompt(nr2char(l:base))
endfunction

function! elephant#identity()
    return '.'
endfunction

function! elephant#vcs_project()
    return fnamemodify(finddir('.git', '.;'), ':h')
endfunction

function! elephant#current_file()
    return expand('%:h')
endfunction

inoremap <silent> <expr> <C-R><C-E> <SID>elephant_init()
cnoremap <silent> <C-R><C-E> <C-R>=<SID>elephant_init()<CR>
```

### How to use it

Using these mappings happens in 3 steps.

#### 1. Invoke the mapping

In Insert mode or Command-line mode, invoke the mapping using `<C-R><C-E>`.

#### 2. Choose a directory

Type a single character to choose which root directory you want completion from. The code above provides two types of roots:

- `f` - The directory that the current file (buffer) resides in
- `p` - The base directory of the Git project the current file belongs to

#### 3. Enter the path or file name

You will be prompted to enter the path or file name relative to the directory specified, with completion available. Press `Enter` when finished.

### Some notes

- This doesn't provide inline completion in Insert mode the way `<C-X><C-F>` does; instead, you will be typing the path or file name on the Command-line prompt (where `:` commands go). Upon pressing `Enter`, the path will be inserted into the buffer.
- The same is true in Command-line mode, which can sometimes be confusing when you hit `Enter` and forget that you still have to hit `Enter` to issue whatever command you were just typing.
- Other directory functions can be registered by adding them into `g:elephant_map`.
- The path inserted will be the full, absolute path. The script can be tweaked to change that behaviour, but I haven't got around to it.

Comment: Didn't quite test the solution, but accepted it because of the completeness. Instead I used the suggest workaround: [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) instead of ctrl+x, ctrl+f.