# Autocomplete filename from current directory in current buffer

Tags: original-vim

So i have a bunch of files in a directory.
I'm editing another file which have broken links/reference to these same files, and i want to edit them.

There isn't too much so doing it manually wouldn't take long...but how do i autocomplete their filename in the current buffer?
example:

```
examplefile.txt
```

to

```
examplefile[TAB]name.txt
```

Where [TAB] is just the Tab key being pressed, for the sake of illustration.

Comment: Have a look at `:h i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F`

Comment: works, though i wish it would autocomplete/work using Tab instead

Comment: You can remap anything to do anything. That's not a big deal. But too often one wants a tab to do a tab. So think twice.

Comment: True, but i'm saying this while being fully aware that i don't use tab :D i'm more of a space guy. @Matt

Comment: Then `inoremap <tab> <c-x><c-f>` What's the problem?

Comment: @NordineLotfi Even as a space guy if you don't use the tab key it might be because you are not aware of [`:h 'expandtab'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27expandtab%27). I would still recommend not to remap tab but Matt's comment should be a good answer.

Comment: Do these answer your question?   https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6432/10604 https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24708/10604

Comment: @NordineLotfi Can you please answer the questions people asked you in the comments? Or if you found a solution which suits you can you post it as an answer? That would be beneficial for the community and people who will find your question in the future.

Comment: Yes, i can confirm what D. Ben posted indeed solve my case @statox sorry for the late answer.